# eclipse maven profiles and classpath

Tags: eclipse, maven-3

I am using for a project eclipse indigo, jboss tools and the embedded version of maven. The jboss version I am using is 6.1 final. I created a simple archillian test, which I can run on the command line without a problem. But when I try to run the same test in eclipse, I activate the profile I created to run the test, and I get this error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:org.jboss.logging.Logger.getLoggerPlugin()Lorg/jboss/logging/LoggerPlugin;
at org.jboss.aop.util.logging.AOPLogger.<init>(AOPLogger.java:63)
at org.jboss.aop.util.logging.AOPLogger.getLogger(AOPLogger.java:44)
at org.jboss.aop.AspectManager.<clinit>(AspectManager.java:109)
at org.jboss.aop.proxy.ProxyFactory.createProxyCtClass(ProxyFactory.java:148)
at org.jboss.aop.proxy.ProxyFactory.createProxyClass(ProxyFactory.java:117)
at org.jboss.aop.proxy.ProxyFactory.createInterfaceProxy(ProxyFactory.java:94)
at org.jboss.aop.proxy.MarshalledInterfaceProxy.readResolve(MarshalledInterfaceProxy.java:72)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadResolve(ObjectStreamClass.java:1061)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1761)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:350)
at java.rmi.MarshalledObject.get(MarshalledObject.java:142)
at org.jnp.interfaces.MarshalledValuePair.get(MarshalledValuePair.java:72)
at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:771)
at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:688)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.jbossas.remote_6.JBossASRemoteContainer.initDeploymentManager(JBossASRemoteContainer.java:204)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.jbossas.remote_6.JBossASRemoteContainer.start(JBossASRemoteContainer.java:87)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.ContainerImpl.start(ContainerImpl.java:198)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerLifecycleController$8.perform(ContainerLifecycleController.java:163)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerLifecycleController$8.perform(ContainerLifecycleController.java:157)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerLifecycleController.forContainer(ContainerLifecycleController.java:255)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerLifecycleController.startContainer(ContainerLifecycleController.java:156)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:90)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.ContainerDeploymentContextHandler.createContainerContext(ContainerDeploymentContextHandler.java:57)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:90)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:134)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:114)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:67)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerLifecycleController$2.perform(ContainerLifecycleController.java:77)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerLifecycleController$2.perform(ContainerLifecycleController.java:70)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerLifecycleController.forEachSuiteContainer(ContainerLifecycleController.java:221)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerLifecycleController.startSuiteContainers(ContainerLifecycleController.java:69)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:90)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:134)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:114)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:67)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.ContainerEventController.execute(ContainerEventController.java:86)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:90)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createSuiteContext(TestContextHandler.java:60)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:90)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:134)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:114)
at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor.beforeSuite(EventTestRunnerAdaptor.java:68)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.run(Arquillian.java:97)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

I think it is related to the ordering of the libraries on the classpath in eclipse when trying to run the test. Does anyone have an idea?

Thanks

Kelly